# display column in horizontal format

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows.

```
[Date]     [Test_Item]     [Result]

1/2/2014     A                  1.1
2/2/2014     B                  31.1     
3/2/2014     C                  20
5/2/2014     A                  44
```

i would like display in the following format

```
[Test_Item]     1/2/2014      2/2/2014     3/2/2014   5/2/2014
   A               1.1    
   B                              31.1
   C                                           20
   A                                                       44
```

How can i achieve this? please suggest the query in this case.

Comment: Do you want to do this using an SQL view, or is this for a PHP system?

Comment: Are you able to use a stored routine? If so, a stored routine with a cursor could achieve the desired results.

Comment: i want to do this using sql view

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic use of the `case` statement:

```
select test_item,
       (case when `date` = '1/2/2014' then result end) as `1/2/2014`,
       (case when `date` = '2/2/2014' then result end) as `2/2/2014`,
       (case when `date` = '3/2/2014' then result end) as `3/2/2014`,
       (case when `date` = '5/2/2014' then result end) as `5/2/2014`
from table t;
```

You don't mention anything about types.  If `date` is actually stored as a date or date/time (as it should be), then you should use ISO standard date formats for comparison, which assuming your format is d/m/yyyy, would be:

```
select test_item,
       (case when `date` = '2014-02-01' then result end) as `1/2/2014`,
       (case when `date` = '2014-02-02' then result end) as `2/2/2014`,
       (case when `date` = '2014-02-03' then result end) as `3/2/2014`,
       (case when `date` = '2014-02-05' then result end) as `5/2/2014`
from table t;
```

Comment: thanks. there is too many records present in the table ,in that case how do i represent this, as specifying all dates is not possible.

Comment: @pheonix4eva . . . MySQL limits the number of columns to some number less than 4,096.  If the problem is typing out the code, then use `information_schema.columns` to list out the columns and then generate the code from the column names.